# what is column editor and template in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

What is the perfect meaning of editor and template in kendo grid

```
 columns: [{
             field: "CategoryId",
             title: "@T("Admin.Catalog.Products.Categories.Fields.Category")",
             width: 200,
             editor: categoryDropDownEditor, 
             template: "#:Category#"
          }]
```

Answer (score 1):

With the **editor** property you can specify a function that is called when editing the cell (of course, the grid must be set to '*editable:true*')

The function could look like this:

```
function numberEditor(container, options) {
  $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
      .appendTo(container)
      .kendoNumericTextBox({
        decimals: 0,
        step    : 1,
        min     : 0
      });
}
```

So when editing a cell, a NumericTextBox is shown which in this case only allows positive (*min:0*) integers (*decimal:0*). In general you can define how the cell can be edited.

The **template** defines how the value is displayed.In your case the value is just shown as it is.
You could for example add some html:

```
template: "<b>#:Category#</b>" // Display bold text 
template: "<a href="example.org">#:Category#</a>" // Display as link
```

The `#:Category#` accesses the data field with that name. You can also use multiple fields in one column:

```
template: "#:Category# / #:SomethingElse#"
```